# Al intentar registrar usuario en DJango me dice "usuario ya existe" así este no exista

Tags: python, html5, django, sqlite, backend

Este es el código que utilizo para registrar los usuarios, por alguna razón no me registra a los usuarios en la base de datos y siempre me aparece el mensaje de "Este usuario ya existe" así este no haya sido registrado

def registro(request):

```
if request.method == 'GET': 

    return render(request, 'registro.html') 

else: 

    if request.POST['password1'] == request.POST['password1']: 

        try: 

            user = User.objects.create_user(username=request.POST['username'], 

            password=request.POST['password1']) 

            user.save() 

            return HttpResponse('Usuario creado satisfactoriamente') 

        except: 

            return HttpResponse('El usuario ya existe') 

    return HttpResponse('Contraseñas no coinciden')
```

He estado buscando información pero supuestamente "no hay errores en el código" así que realmente no sé que es lo que sucede. Hace poco que estoy utilizando DJango, de hecho, aún lo estoy aprendiendo, me ayudaría un montón si pudiesen decirme que ocasiona el error

Comment: Tu try catch cuando algo sale mal dice que salga el msj de "El usuario ya existe", puede que tengas algo mal en tu función save() si es que este bloque de código que enseñas no tiene algún error

Comment: Como tienes tu modelo?, se me ocurre que puedes tener el username en el modelo como único o estas realizando una validación en alguno de los datos que envías al "create_user", si pudieras mostrar mas información y te podamos ayudar mejor.